# Can't apply filter with data returned from $asArray in AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

I can't apply filter as normal with data returned from AngularFire. It's a surprise that when I run it on Plnkr, the filter works. But when I run it on Firefox on my computer, it doesn't work and doesn't show any error in console.

Here is my code:-

Javascript:-

```
angular.module('myApp',['firebase'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $firebase){
    //get all categories
  var catRef = new Firebase('https://url/goes/here');
  $scope.cats = $firebase(catRef).$asArray();
  console.log($scope.cats);
});
```

Html:-

```
 <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Category</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Search query: <input type="text" ng-model="query" placehoder="Search..."></li>
      <li ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:query">{{cat.name}}</li>
    </ul>
 </body>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqVQ3EiTVhwVnrFdAfWm?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/e0ozp82k/